# Why I got this error message on my React Native code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

I got this erros message but I could not solve it yet. Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8cHs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gStx3.png)

Comment: remember: not using image for code.

Comment: Your `</SafeAreaView>` closing tag is missing `<`

Comment: First, don't post an image of code. SO supports markdown so that you can copy/paste your snippet. Second, if you read the error, it says exactly what the problem is. You StyleSheet object is malformed.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close enclosing tag

```
1 SafeAreaView 
2 Textinput
```

Please have look in below code

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, TextInput} from 'react-native';

const FirstTextInput = () => {
  const [text, onChangeText] = React.useState('Useless Text');
  const [number, onChangeNumber] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={value => onChangeText(value)}
        value={text}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={value => onChangeNumber(value)}
        value={number}
        placeholder="Place Holder"
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
});

export default FirstTextInput;
```